# How to use Mongoose find query in express router?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to use Mongoose find query to get the complete list of documents held in my mongodb. However for some reason, the query stopped working and hasn't worked since. I believe all my code is correct, and its not giving me any error messages either.

Routes\image.js

```
const router = require('express').Router();
let imageModel = require('../Models/image');


router.get('/collection',(req,res) => {
    imageModel.find({},(err,data) => {
        if(err) {
            res.status(500).json({msg:"Cant find collection",err})
        } else {
            res.send(data);
        }
    })
})


module.exports = router;
```

Models \ image

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let imageSchema = new Schema({
    name:String,
    desc:String,
    imgUrl:String
});
let model = new mongoose.model('Image',imageSchema);
module.exports = model;
```

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5001;

// Routes
const imageRoute = require('./Routes/image');

app.use(express.json());

app.use(cors());
require('dotenv').config()
require('./db.config');


app.use('/image',imageRoute);

app.get('/',(req,res) => {
    res.send('First Route!')
})

app.listen(PORT,() => {
    console.log(`listening on port ${PORT}`)
})
```

Comment: Any debugging info you would like to share? How about putting a `console.log` right before `imageModel.find` to see if your code even makes it there... It's tricky to help when all we had to go by is "this code used to work, but now it doesn't".

Comment: The route seems to work fine, I added a console.log which was successful. I think the issue lies with the mongoose query. The error object returns an {} unfortunately :/

Comment: If `err` returns an empty object, then `if(err) {` will be true and your 500 error will be triggered. Is that what you're seeing?

Comment: Yup, I'm using postman to check my API and it returns a 500 error

Comment: Get rid of the `new` in `let model = new mongoose.model...`. Just leave `let model = mongoose.model...`

Comment: It seems to be working now .